# Only filter, no input text or number

Tags: ag-grid

In the demo a function is shown that can not be found in the documentation.

How to make?

[x] support request

Only filter, no input text or number

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the set filter with floating filters turned on.

It's in the documentation, but maybe it's a bit hard to find:

- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/
- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filter-component/

The set filter is an enterprise feature.

The code for that [demo grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) is here, CTRL+F for "countryCellRenderer" to see the relevant parts:

https://www.ag-grid.com/example.js